# what is level curves? what is non-critical level curves?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, morse-theory, mapping-class-group

in this [paper](https://sci-hub.se/10.1515/crll.2000.028) we have **non-critical level curves**.

"On the Teichmüller tower of mapping class
groups
By Allen Hatcher at Ithaca, Pierre Lochak at Paris and Leila Schneps at Besançon "

We have :

Let $I=[0,1]$. We consider Morse functions $f:(\Sigma, \partial \Sigma) \rightarrow(I, 0)$ whose critical points all lie in the interior of $\Sigma$. To such a Morse function we associate a finite graph $\Gamma(f)$, which is the quotient space of $\Sigma$ obtained by collapsing all points in the same component of a **level set** $f^{-1}(a)$ to a single point in $\Gamma(f)$. If we assume $f$ is generic, so that all critical points have distinct critical values, then the vertices of $\Gamma(f)$ all have valence 1 or 3 and arise from critical points of $f$ or from boundary components of $\Sigma$. Namely, boundary components give rise to vertices of valence 1, as do local maxima and minima of $f$, while saddles of $f$ produce vertices of valence 3 . See figure 2 of $[\mathrm{HT}]$ for pictures. We can associate to such a function $f$ a maximal multicurve $C(f)$, unique up to isotopy, by either of the following two equivalent procedures:
(1) Choose one point in the interior of each edge of $\Gamma(f)$, take the loops in $\Sigma$ which these points correspond to, then delete those loops which bound disks in $\Sigma$ or are isotopic to boundary components, and replace collections of mutually isotopic loops by a single loop.
(2) Let $\Gamma_{0}(f)$ be the unique smallest subgraph of $\Gamma(f)$ which $\Gamma(f)$ deformation retracts to and which contains all the vertices corresponding to boundary components of $\Sigma$. If $\Gamma_{0}(f)$ has vertices of valence 2 , regard these not as vertices but as interior points of edges. In each edge of $\Gamma_{0}(f)$ not having a valence 1 vertex as an endpoint, choose an interior point distinct from the points which were vertices of valence 2 . Then let $C(f)$ consist of the loops in $\Sigma$ corresponding to these chosen points of $\Gamma_{0}(f)$.

Every maximal multicurve arises as $C(f)$ for some generic $f:(\Sigma, \partial \Sigma) \rightarrow(I, 0) .$ To obtain such an $f$, one can first define it near the loops of the given multicurve and the loops of $\partial \Sigma$ so that all these loops are **noncritical level curves**, then extend to a function defined on all of $\Sigma$, then perturb this function to be a generic Morse function.

> what is **level curves**? what is  **non-critical level curves**?

Comment: The link isn't accessible everywhere. Could you make a self-contained question?

Comment: This is not exactly what I meant by "self-contained". You should add context in which the terms would make sense so that we can bring you some definition.

Comment: @Didier . I edited for second time .

Comment: In that context, a level curve is a subset of the form $f^{-1}(\{c\})$ for some $c \in \Bbb R$. It is non-critical if all its point are regular points, i.e if the differential of $f$ is non-zero. It is a synonym of level-set in this context (the codimension is 1)

Comment: The authors of the paper you are reading expect (from the reader) familiarity with basic differential topology. Did you take any classes or read any textbooks on the subject?

Comment: @MoisheKohan . no i have no reference for basic differential topology . please give me some basic  reference . thanks .

Comment: "Differential Topology" by Guillemin and Pollack is a gentle introduction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The classic example of a Morse function is the height on an upright torus. In the diagram, the torus is cut off at the bottom, creating a boundary curve in red; the three critical levels (the two figure-8 curves and the point at top) are blue, typical non-critical levels are green, and the associated graph is at right.

[image: The graph associated to a Morse function]

Comment: what is definition of height function in general ? also what is associated graph ?

Comment: _Height_ is an informal way of saying "Morse function with distinct critical values." The _associated graph_ is defined in the quoted passage of the Hatcher-Lochak-Schneps paper.